# Flutter Firestore chat app how to seen message?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I guess I couldn't understand the logic of the chat message being seen.
I have 1 save message  method and 2 stream instant data reading methods.

This is my save method:

```
Future<bool> saveMessage(MessageModel model) async {
 var messageID = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("konusmalar").doc().id;
 var save= model.toMap();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Chats")
        .doc(_myDocID)
        .collection("messages")
        .doc(messageID)
        .set(save);
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Chats")
        .doc(_myDocID)
        .set({
      "seenMessage": true, // ?????
    });
    map.update("isSender", (value) => false);
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Chats")
        .doc(_reciverID)
        .collection("messages")
        .doc(messageID)
        .set(save);
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Chats").doc(_reciverID).set({
      "seenMessage": false,
    });

    return true;
  }
```

My 2 stream methods are here:

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>> getMessage() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Chats").doc(_reciverID).update({
     "seenMessage": true,
    });
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Chats")
        .doc(_myDocID)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }

  Future<Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> checkSeenStream(
      String currentUserID, String sohbetEdilenUserID) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Chats")
        .doc(_reciverID)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

The thing is, when the chat is opened, my logic works properly. `seenMessage` returns true to the other user, and I can put the phrase "message seen UI" in the UI section (opposite user UI). BUT since this `seenMessage` value changes when the message is saved, it goes false and the "message seen UI" statement does not appear because its value changes. How can I proceed here?